# Change the selected option of HTML Select element: behavior is different when I use cursor

Tags: javascript, html, select

I have written a simple JS code that changes the selected option of an HTML Select element. Although the selected option changes to the desired value, the page doesn't respond to that. But when I use the cursor to change the selected options, the page truly responds. Do you have any idea what's the problem?

I think the problem is not due to my option toggling code, btw, it's the JS function I use:

```
function changeTheSelection() {
    var selectElement = document.getElementById(selectInputId);

    var opts = selectElement.options;
    console.log("num of options found: " + opts.length);

    for (var idx = 0; idx < opts.length; idx++) {
        var opt = opts[idx];

        if (!opt.selected) {
            selectElement.selectedIndex = idx;
            console.log("option " + idx + " selected.");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem!
I have to add this:

```
selectElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

Sorry for this silly question...